# Renaming multiple video files using RE and OS

Tags: python, regex, operating-system, mkv

I recently downloaded a large number of `mkv` files with names formatted like "South Park S01E01 Cartman Gets an Anal Probe (640x480) [Phr0stY].mkv". I want to strip all of the text except for the actual episode names. Here is the code I have so far.

```
rootdir = '/Users/me/Documents/Test/'
for ii in os.listdir(rootdir):
    try:
        for kk in os.listdir(rootdir + ii):
            try:
                    new = re.sub('South\sPark\sS[0-9][0-9]E[0-9][0-9]\s', '', kk)
                    new1 = re.sub('\s\([0-9]+x[0-9]+\)\s\[Phr0stY\]', '', new)
                    os.rename(rootdir + ii + kk, rootdir + ii + new1)
            except:
                    pass
    except:
        pass
```

Everything works fine up until the `os.rename` line where it stops and causes the `except` clause to execute. When I print `new1` the correct string is returned. Can anyone see why the rename isn't working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `os.path.join` to combine the components of a file path, not `+`.